# Basic authentication accessing page via HTTP

Tags: php, authentication

I have a requirement that I'm not sure how to start with and am unfamiliar with in as much as how to go about it.

I have some PHP files located on a server running apache and PHP (which I have full access to)  which I call via a cron job directly via PHP in the form of, for example:

```
*/10 * * * * php /var/www/html/file.php
```

This works fine and the file executes correctly.

I also need to load the file externally via a standard HTTP request, such as http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/file.php

BUT...

I really need some kind of basic authentication so that only I can access this files publicly. I know how to add password protection, but I was hoping to maybe pass this in the URL, in the form of http://user:pass@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/file.php or somehow in the header(?) rather then having to enter a username and password each time I want to load the file.

I have read, but did not fully understand, that I could send a token in the end of the URL that would identify me and authenticated such as http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/file?secret=token which would be my ideal solution.

Any advice on how to approach this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be this can help you as far as I understand your problem

```
    <?php
    if (!isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'])) {
    header("WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm=\"Private Area\"");
    header("HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized");
    print "Sorry - you need valid credentials to be granted access!\n";
    exit;
    } else {
    if (($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] == 'paul') && ($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'] == 'hudson')) {
        print "Welcome to the private area!";
    } else {
        header("WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm=\"Private Area\"");
        header("HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized");
        print "Sorry - you need valid credentials to be granted access!\n";
        exit;
     }
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: thank you. How would I call this from in the HTTP URL? How would I pass this info? WOuld it be http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/file.php?user=paul&pass=hudson

Comment: Now I can't seem to use this via the CLI PHP calling it like php /var/www/html/file.php How do I pass the username and password in CLI? Thanks

Comment: not sure about calling from http url, but you can directly call the URL and pop up would ask for authentication, Also using CURL `code` curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "username:password"); //Your credentials goes here
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $curl_post_data);
$curl_response = curl_exec($curl);

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the internet...

[GOOGLE](https://www.google.hu/search?q=cron%20php%20http%20auth) -> 1. result

> 45 * * * * /usr/bin/lynx -auth=username:password -source
>   http://example.com/cron.php
>
> 45 * * * * /usr/bin/wget --user=username --password=password -O - -q
>   http://example.com/cron.php
>
> 45 * * * * /usr/bin/curl --anyauth --user username:password --silent
>   --compressed http://example.com/cron.php

Comment: Many times I regret using this website because I ask for help and advice and get voted down and these responses. I *DID* use the internet to search, I didn't immediately find exactly what I was looking for, hence my post. Thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

```
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC); curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "username:password"); //Your credentials goes here curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true); curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $curl_post_data); $curl_response = curl_exec($curl)
```